# How to convert the body of an email into a .pdf

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, office-2007

I have to convert an email into `.pdf` without the head which includes the information about the date, the receivers, cc, etc. 
Does anyone how to do that the easy way?

My other solution would be to copy the whole body of the mail into a new word-document and save it as a `.pdf`, but I don't know how to copy the whole body via VBA either.

[EDIT JMax from comments]
Here is the code I've tried:

```
sBody = oMail.HTMLBody
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
wrdApp.Documents.Add "C:\asd\Releasemail.dotx"
wrdApp.Documents("Dokument1").Bookmarks().Item("Releaseinhalt").Range.Text = sBody
```

I get my whole HTML printed in the .doc, but I want the body of the mail as it's shown in Outlook, not the markup, that creates that look. For example, if I press `Ctrl + a` and `Ctrl + c` in Outlook and press `Ctrl + v` in Word, I get the text with all its styling copied to Word.
How to do that in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get only the body of a mail, you have to use this kind of statement:

```
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Body = Msg.HTMLBody
```

You can find another example on [this blog](http://jeremyslade.com/2009/04/outlook-vba-macro-to-post-email-body-to-the-web/) and [on VBA Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=942)

Have a try and come back when you will have an issue on some code.

[EDIT]
To get the body content instead of HTML, you can use : `Msg.Body` but you will then probably loose the formatting of the message.

Comment: I still don't know how to actually print Body  or paste it into a word-document. I'm pretty unexperienced when it comes to outlook + word vba.

Comment: Yet, your question doesn't show any reseach effort. I can understand that you are unexperienced but you could **search** and **try** before asking to someone else to do everything.

Comment: Now, when I use `sBody = oMail.HTMLBody
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
wrdApp.Documents.Add "C:\asd\Releasemail.dotx"
wrdApp.Documents("Dokument1").Bookmarks().Item("Releaseinhalt").Range.Text = sBody
`, I get my whole HTML printed in the .doc, but I want the body of the mail as it's shown in Outlook, not the markup, that creates that look. For example, if I press **Ctrl + a** and **Ctrl + c** in Outlook and press **Ctrl + v** in Word, I get the text with all its styling copied to Word. How to do that in VBA?

Comment: And btw: Maybe you misunderstood me, I already experimented for some days before I posted here, so I knew how to get the body to a variable, but then it seemed to be a dead end for me, so I didn't see a reason to post it here.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can have a try and see if it works. I can't test it right here.

Comment: Hmm, with `sBody = oMail.Body` it doesn't return anything, not even an error. I'll see if I have to swap something in there...thanks so far, also for editing my original post =)

Comment: You're welcome. A complete question, even with the code that didn't work, is the best way to get relevant answers... I'll see if I can find anything else about getting text from message